# while comparing the reverse of the string to the original It return TRUE instead of FALSE

Tags: java, string, reverse, stringbuilder

''''
while comparing the reverse of the string to the original It return TRUE instead of FALSE
''''

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.StringBuilder;
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String A = "java";
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append(A);
            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println(str.reverse());
            System.out.println(str == str.reverse());
            if (str.equals(str.reverse())) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The equals method is shorting out on object equality, not value equality.  This will get what you're aiming for.

```
if (str.toString().equals(str.reverse().toString())) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
   System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: oh, so we need to convert the StringBuilder str to a normal String.???

Comment: Yes, or to a different StringBuilder.  If you look at most equals() methods, the first line is usually a direct object comparison.  Since you're comparing the same object, as opposed to the value of that object, it's returning true.